# 100 errors from my typedef

Tags: c, structure, syntax-error, typedef, visual-c++-2010

This is part of my code:

```
#ifndef INTPROC_OPERATIONS_H
#define INTPROC_OPERATIONS_H

#define MAX_OPERATIONS 256
#define USED_OPERATIONS 8
#define MAX_OPCODE 256
#define OPCODE_TYPE unsigned char

#define OPERANDS_TYPE unsigned char

#include <malloc.h>
#include "executions.h"

typedef struct
{
    OPCODE_TYPE opcode;
    const char * name;
    OPERANDS_TYPE operands_length;
    int (* execute)(char * operands_start, char operands_length);
} OPERATION;

OPERATION * operations[MAX_OPERATIONS];

extern void init_operations();
#define operations_init() init_operations()
extern OPERATION parse_operation(OPCODE_TYPE opcode); //syntax error type

#endif
```

code.c

```
#include "code.h"
CODEFILE * create_file()
{
    CODEFILE * ret = (CODEFILE*)malloc(sizeof(CODEFILE));
    ret->actual_instruction = 0; //'actual_instruction' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
    ret->length = 0; //'length' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
    ret->name = ""; //'name' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
    ret->start = 0; /'start' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'

    return ret;
}
```

NOTE: code.h is including file operation.h, I've ridden somwhere that cascade include can be problematic when using typedef...

As it's written in the heading of question, I'm getting 100 errors from Visual C++ 2010 when I'm trying to compile this code. The errors are caused by some mistake in my typedef.

```
Error   95  error C2039: 'actual_instruction' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
Error   96  error C2039: 'length' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
Error   97  error C2039: 'name' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
Error   98  error C2039: 'start' : is not a member of 'CODEFILE'
...
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
Error   64  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
Error   76  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

The header file which contains this structure is being included to C files (i'm also using it in other headers). Errors like `syntax error : 'type'` are in include file, the others are in files in which is include file (with members) being included. Doed anybody know where is the problem? Please help.

Comment: I don't see any code that could produce the errors you've shown, can you post the violating code?

Comment: in code.h include header, should I paste code of CODEFILE here?

Comment: Yes, obviously... The error message states the variables you try to set are not part of the struct, so the struct definition seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You surely have a syntax error in the definition of the struct `CODEFILE` that prevents the compiler from parsing the names of the fields. Then, when these fields are used, it fails again in a cascade of errors.

In these cases, just concentrate on the very first error.

If you use VS, find the first error in the **"Output"** window, not the **"Errors"** window. The latter is known for reordering the errors for *your convenience*.